# Older Shimano Road Brake Levers vs Newer Ones Quality (SLR vs Super SLR)

Tags: road-bike, brakes, shimano, vintage, brake-levers

I'm owner of relatively new (non STI) levers of low Sora/Tiagra level, they are Shimano bl-r400 (Super SLR).

Now i'm thinking of replacing them with pretty Dura Ace BL-7402 (SLR). These come from early 90-s i guess, and were top of the line atm.
I dont care about weight difference.

So my question, is there any significant difference in braking quality (this is most imprortant), construction quality difference etc, considering the fact that there are 20 years between them.
Does 'Super SLR' really matter or it is marketing stuff..?

BTW, i use single Pivots DA BR-7402, so their generation match with desired BL-7402.

Thanks for sharing your ideas about that.

small fix: i discovered my current Levers are Ultegra bl-r600, which are a little bit more fine made i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between SLR and Super SLR is mechanical advantage: Super SLR moves the cable for slightly longer distance with slightly less force. In principle, the brakes work best when brakes and levers are designed to match (like the configuration you are asking about), but the difference is so small that mixed setup (like what you have now) does work too.

Comment: Ah you know, that might be a little problem in my case. I have unusual internal cable routing (frame is custom), and it does not work perfectly fine, so i have to use some force using rear brake. I worry switching to older ones now

Comment: Have you replaced the cable and housing? How old are your brake pads?

Comment: They are (were) brand new, so it's ok. But rim is non-machined (Velocity Aero), however, producing company says it's completely fine to use it with brakes. It's a little bit more complicated as you can see, but nevermind